# Can Rails sort a CSV file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, csv

I'm exporting a CSV from many different sources which makes it very hard to sort before putting it into the CSV.

```
csv = CSV.generate col_sep: '#' do |csv|
  ... adding a few columns here
end
```

Now, it would be awesome if I was able to sort this CSV by the 2nd column. Is that in any way possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're trying to sort before writing, it depends on your data structure, in which i'll need to see your code a bit more. For reading a csv, you can convert it to hash and sort by header name even:

```
rows = []
CSV.foreach('mycsvfile.csv', headers: true) do |row|
  rows << row.to_h
end

rows.sort_by{ |row| row['last_name'] }
```

**Edit** to use sort_by, thanks to max williams.

Comment: You've also got the `sort_by` method which is a bit nicer:  `rows.sort_by{|row| row['last_name']}`

Comment: There's also, this, which doesn't apply in this case but which you can do if you're sorting by a method, which is even neater:  `rows.sort_by(&:size)` which is equivalent to `rows.sort_by{|row| row.size}`

Comment: I do know of that :). I use that pattern with map a fair bit, but yeah doesn't work with hash keys.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you would sort by column number:

```
rows = []
CSV.foreach('mycsvfile.csv', headers: true) do |row|
  # collect each row as an array of values only
  rows << row.to_h.values
end

# sort in place by the 2nd column
rows.sort_by! { |row| row[1] }

rows.each do |row|
  # do stuff with your now sorted rows
end
```